# How to transport NSManagedObject subclass between classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

We have made a repository layer for interacting with Core Data that have methods such as `allItems()`, `addItem:(Item*)item` where item being the NSManagedObject subclass. When we need to save an item we invoke the method on the repository passing the subclass instance as an argument. However, that does not work because we can't use the `init`initializer and the context is hidden inside the repository.

What is the best way to transfer objects when you have an architecture like this? Is making a ItemDTO an passing that around an option? Or are there better ways to solve this such as not using subclassed NSManagedObject at all and just use key/value that works.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little further? Is your issue that you can't create new managed objects outside the repository layer, or that you can't save the objects later on?

Comment: The problem is that the context is "hidden" inside the repository layer and I don't want to leak that outside the repository layer. I want to use that as a solid point of abstraction.

Comment: You are aware that every managed object has a pointer to the managed object context? So that particular cat is out of the bag, sort of.

Comment: Yes, but listen. I want to create let say an Item object in the controller...then pass it through the service and repository layer where the context is. In Java EE (JPA) you do it, objects is not that attached to a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I <s>wrote</s>copy-pasted a sample project that hides the context from model custom classes: [branch 10583736](https://github.com/madmw/CoreDataQuestions/tree/10583736).

*(it's not final production code, just a quick example, don't expect it to deal with multithreading or weird errors)*

Hiding the context to custom classes is just a matter of defining custom methods to deal with every situation where you normally will request the context and use it.

You can define a class for the store layer **without exposing the context**:

```
@interface DataStore : NSObject

+ (id)shared;

- (void)saveAll;
- (NSEntityDescription *)entityNamed:(NSString *)name;
/* more custom methods ... */
- (NSManagedObject *)fetchEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate;

@end
```

I suggest to use a common ancestor for all your custom model classes to save some typing. This class can be the only one that interacts with `DataStore` directly. It doesn't have access to the context.

```
@interface DataObject : NSManagedObject

+ (NSString *)entityName;
+ (NSEntityDescription *)entity;
- (void)save;
/* more custom methods ... */

@end
```

Finally your model custom classes defines any method you need probably taking advantage of whatever is provided by the superclass:

```
@interface Card : DataObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * question;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * answer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Deck *deck;

/* return a new card */
+ (Card *)card; 

/* more custom methods ... */

@end
```

The *master* branch has a more usual approach where model classes obtain the context and work with it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the architecture you are using isn't suited to core data. To keep using it (which you should) you have to do one of two things. I am assuming your "repository layer" is implemented as a singleton, or at least that the objects creating new managed objects have access to it.

- Expose your managed object context to other objects, typically as a property on your repository layer.
- Have your repository layer initialise and return the objects for you. This would involve passing in an entity name and getting back a new managed object of the appropriate entity type or class.

If you find yourself fighting the frameworks and coming up with excessive abstractions, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you'd want the controllers creating the `NSManagedObject` subclasses to have a pointer to the `NSManagedObjectContext`. In this way, you could indeed call the initializer.

The problem with what you are trying to do is that the items cannot exist without the context. That is done purposely so that Core Data knows if you are talking about a new object or an object that is already in the persistent store.

You could use DTOs but you'd end up with a lot of duplication so it gets ugly quick. In my opinion, you should consider making your controllers aware of the Core Data context so that it can properly either retrieve or init the items (managed objects) and essentially use the `NSManagedObjectContext` as your repository layer.

Remember that the `NSManagedObjectContext` IS a persistence abstraction layer and you can back it up with other persistent store implementations if you want, including your own [custom ones](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HTMLStore/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004009).